# Outlook automation

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, automation

What do people here use to automate work with outlook? Programming scripts to filter messages instead of using the GUI? 
A macro to email out notices based on an Excel list with dates?

I'm looking for further ideas on automating the paperwork parts of my day.

Comment: Google vor "Outlook VBA" and you should get lots of scripts. But main question is, what solution fits your demands? (1) Try first to identify which worksteps you are frequently doing manually with Outlook. (2) Then define which step you want to have automated. (3) Then think about the implementation.      However everything has to start with step (1)

Answer (score 1):

VBA is built into Outlook, so you have the full programming ability of Visual Basic available, but that also requires at least some programming skill, and probably a lot of googling for examples of programming the Outlook application. Difficlut but in my opinion worth it if you cannot find an add-on that does what you want already, or if you just enjoy tinkering. You can access the Visual Basic Editor from the **Tools | Macro | Visual Basic Editor** menus, or by using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>.

Comment: I know about that, I was more looking for what sort of things would you automate in your daily work.